# Html email template not working outlook

Tags: html, css, email, outlook, email-templates

I've searched a lot before coming here.

I'm trying to use a `background-image`, but when I send it to outlook it doesn't appears. Can you help me to find the solution for this issue?

```html
<table width="600" border="0" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" valign="top" style="padding-bottom: 10px;overflow:hidden !important;border-radius: 0px 0px 0px 0px; background-color: #efefef; vertical-align: middle; max-width: 600px;">
  <tr style="background:;#efefef;" align="center" width="564px">
    <td width="10%">&nbsp;</td>

    <td style="background-image: url('https://www.dcg.com.br/emkt/17-07/bg_02.jpg');" bgcolor="#fff" background="https://www.dcg.com.br/emkt/17-07/bg_02.jpg" align="center" max-width="600px" style="font-family: Arial, sans-serif; font-size:18px; line-height:24px;  color:#6f757c;">
      <p align="center" style="display:inline-block;background:transparent;text-align:center;font-size:18px;font-family:Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;box-sizing: border-box; ">
        <br>
        <strong style="font-size:27px">Eletrolar Show</strong><br/> A maior feira B2B da América Latina
        <br/>
      </p>
    </td>
    <td width="10%">&nbsp;</td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

Comment: Perhaps outlook blocks downloading of images. Are other images loading?

Comment: only if the users allow it

Answer (score 3):

background images using `background` are not supported by Outlook, Notes, certain versions of Android and a few other email clients.

- https://www.campaignmonitor.com/css/color-background/background/

The only way to get a background image to work with Outlook is to use VML code. I posted an example and a link to the JS Fiddle code.

- https://jsfiddle.net/wallyglenn/7zLaLrfx/15/

  ```
  <div style="background-color:#ff0000; width:600px;">
  <table role="presentation" align="center" border="0" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" width="600" height="450">
    <tr>
      <td background="http://www.gwally.com/news/photos/catintinfoilhat.jpg" bgcolor="#ff0000" valign="middle" style="text-align: center; background-position: center center !important; background-size: cover !important;">
      <!--[if gte mso 9]>
        <v:rect xmlns:v="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:vml" fill="true" stroke="false" style="width:600px;height:450px; background-position: center center !important;">
        <v:fill type="tile" src="http://www.gwally.com/news/photos/catintinfoilhat.jpg" color="#FF0000" />
        <v:textbox inset="0,0,0,0">
      <![endif]-->
      <div>
      <table role="presentation" align="center" border="0" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" width="100%">
        <tr>
          <td valign="middle" style="text-align: center; padding: 40px; font-family: sans-serif; font-size: 15px; line-height: 140%; color: #ffffff;">
            <h1 style="text-align: center; color: #ffffff;-webkit-text-stroke-width: 1px; -webkit-text-stroke-color: black; font-family: Arial, san-serif;">
              Background Image with text on top
            </h1>
          </td>
        </tr>
      </table>
      </div>
      <!--[if gte mso 9]>
      </v:textbox>
      </v:rect>
      <![endif]-->
      </td>
    </tr>
  </table>
  </div>
  ```

I tested this code using http://litmus.com just before I posted it to ensure it currently works in every email client that supports background images in some form.

What you should see is a 600x450px image, a red background for contrast, `<h1>` text on top of the image with some css to help it stand out in contrast.

To use this, swap out the image url, adjust the size, change the color and delete the text if you don't need it.

Good luck.

Answer (score 1):

As information is very less so difficult to identify the exact issue but you can try by setting `width="100%"` instead of `width="600"`.

Current is:

```
<table width="600" border="0" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" valign="top" style="padding-bottom: 10px;overflow:hidden !important;border-radius: 0px 0px 0px 0px; background-color: #efefef; vertical-align: middle; max-width: 600px;">
```

Change to:

```
<table width="100%" border="0" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" valign="top" style="padding-bottom: 10px;overflow:hidden !important;border-radius: 0px 0px 0px 0px; background-color: #efefef; vertical-align: middle; max-width: 600px;">
```

Comment: I tried it, and the background image still do not appearing. The main issue that Im facing is that all the tr have to be max width 600 and align center. Thats why the table is sat as 600 width not 100%. Sorry for the bad english :( thanks for helping

Answer (score 1):

I found out that you cannot use background-images for outlook that is installed in your desktop or notebook. There is some sites that can help if you want a background image for the body and it works. But when we talk about tables, tr, td outlook does not recognize it as a background-image.

Thank you very much for your help. Person like as who develop email templates knows how hard is to figure out how to write the best html that we can. <3

Answer (score 0):

CSS background support isn't great for Outlook. You may need to replace with the VML equivalent. There's a tool for this here: https://backgrounds.cm/

Just paste in your img URL, select your fallback bg-color, and select "single table cell". Then, you'll want to replace the opening and ending td tags with the output provided.

Answer (score 0):

I add this code to my table.
It does not work on Outlook on Windows and that is what the bgcolor is for.

```
style="background-position: center center !important; background-size: cover !important;" background="http:wwww.yourlink.com/folder/image.jpg" bgcolor="#9cb0b0"
```