# E-Mail Template looks good on live server but it's broken when I send it via mail

Tags: html, css, email, templates, gmail

I tried to create my first E-mail template, when I open it by Live Server it looks good, but when I send it via mail with putsmail it looks very crappy and broken.
I tried to upload pictures online but it doesn't change anything.
On code snippet it also looks good so I think that code is fine?
I have run out of ideas, is there anyone who can help me?

Mail preview

[image] -

Live Server preview

[image]

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
  <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
  <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge" />
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
  <title>VANS E-Mail Template</title>
  <style type="text/css">
    body {
      margin: 0;
      background-color: #cccccc;
    }
    table {
      border-spacing: 0;
    }
    td {
      padding: 0;
    }
    img {
      border: 0;
    }
    .wrapper {
      width: 100%;
      table-layout: fixed;
      background-color: #cccccc;
      padding-bottom: 40px;
      font-family: 'Segoe UI', Tahoma, Geneva, Verdana, sans-serif;
    }
    .main {
      background-color: #ffffff;
      margin: 0 auto;
      width: 100%;
      max-width: 600px;
      border-spacing: 0;
      color: #4a4a4a;
    }
    .two-columns {
      text-align: center;
      font-size: 0;
      padding: 40px 0;
    }
    .two-columns .column {
      width: 100%;
      max-width: 300px;
      display: inline-block;
      vertical-align: top;
      text-align: center;
      font-size: 18px;
      padding-bottom: 40px;
    }
    .button {
      background-color: #C9192E;
      color: #ffffff;
      text-decoration: none;
      padding: 15px 20px;
      border-radius: 2px;
    }
    .banner {
      max-width: 600px;
    }
    .container {
      position: relative;
      text-align: center;
      color: white;
      margin-top: 0px;
    }
    .container2 {
      position: relative;
      text-align: center;
      margin-top: -60px;
      display: block;
    }
    .background {
      height: 70px;
      width: 600px;
      margin-top: 0px;
      background-color: #1C1C1C;
    }
    .background2 {
      height: 70px;
      width: 600px;
      background-color: #1C1C1C;
      background: #1C1C1C;
      background-size: 100%;
    }
    .background-text {
      font-size: 40px;
      position: absolute;
      top: 50%;
      left: 50%;
      transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
      text-decoration: none;
      color: white;
    }
    .background-text2 {
      font-size: 40px;
      position: absolute;
      top: 50%;
      left: 50%;
      transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
      text-decoration: none;
      color: white;
      white-space: nowrap;
    }
    .first {
      margin-left: 15px;
      margin-top: 15px;
      z-index: 9;
      display: block;
      position: absolute;
    }
    .first-text {
      font-size: 32px;
      padding: 0;
      margin-top: -30px;
      margin-left: 45px;
      color: #272727;
    }
    .first2-text {
      font-size: 22px;
      padding: 0;
      margin-top: -30px;
      margin-left: 50px;
      color: #272727;
    }
    .second {
      margin-left: 315px;
      margin-top: 40px;
      display: block;
      position: absolute;
    }
    .second-text {
      font-size: 32px;
      padding: -300px;
      margin-left: 380px;
      line-height: 0;
      color: #272727;
    }
    .second2-text {
      font-size: 22px;
      padding: -300px;
      margin-left: 380px;
      line-height: 0;
      color: #272727;
    }
    .third {
      margin-top: 290px;
      margin-left: 15px;
    }
    .third-text {
      font-size: 32px;
      padding: -300px;
      margin-top: -275px;
      margin-left: 340px;
      line-height: 0;
      color: #272727;
    }
    .third2-text {
      font-size: 22px;
      padding: -300px;
      margin-left: 340px;
      line-height: 0;
      background: "#D0CFC8";
      background-size: "100%";
      color: #272727;
    }
    .see-more {
      margin-left: 380px;
      margin-top: 80px;
      font-size: 26px;
    }
    .background-rect {
      background: #D0CFC8;
      height: 150px;
      width: 600px;
    }
    .icons {
      position: relative;
      display: block;
      margin-top: -58px;
      margin-left: auto;
      margin-right: auto;
    }
  </style>
</head>
<body>
  <center class="wrapper">
    <table class="main" width="100%">
      <!-- LOGO SECTION -->
      <!-- BANNER IMAGE !! -->
      <tr>
        <td>
          <a href="#"><img src="https://i.ibb.co/MPsmk9q/banner.png" alt="Banner" class="banner"> </a>
        </td>
      </tr>
      <!-- BACKGROUND COLOR TEXT !!-->
      <tr>
        <td class="container">
          <div class="background"></div>
          <a href="#" class="background-text">SHOP CLASSICS</a>
        </td>
        </td>
      </tr>
      <!-- TWO COLUMN SECTION -->
      <tr>
        <td>
          <table width="100%">
            <tr>
              <td class="two-columns" style="background-color: #D8D7D3; padding-bottom: 0;">
                <table class="column">
                  <tr>
                    <td>
                      <a href="#"><img src="https://i.ibb.co/YfSffKs/women.webp" alt="Women" title="Women" width="300" style="max-width: 300px; padding-bottom: 60px; padding-top: 30px;"></a>
                      <a href="#" class="button">BUY WOMENS</a>
                    </td>
                  </tr>
                </table>
                <table class="column">
                  <tr>
                    <td class="column">
                      <a href="#"><img src="https://i.ibb.co/bvHdthf/men.webp" alt="Men" title="Men" width="300" style="max-width: 300px; padding-bottom: 60px; padding-top: 30px; -webkit-transform: scaleX(-1);
                                                    transform: scaleX(-1);"></a>
                      </a>
                      <a href="#" class="button">BUY  MEN</a>
                    </td>
                  </tr>
                </table>
              </td>
            </tr>
          </table>
        </td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td class="container">
          <div class="background"></div>
          <a href="#" class="background-text2">OUR LATEST COLLECTION</a>
        </td>
      </tr>

      <!-- FOOTER SECTION -->
      <tr style="background: #D0CFC8; background-size: 100%;">
        <td>
          <div class="first">
            <a href="#"><img src="https://i.ibb.co/YQ09v1N/Eco.webp" alt="Eco" style="max-width: 350px"></a>
            <div class="first-text">
              <p>PAISLEY PATTERN</p>
            </div>
            <div class="first2-text">
              <p>Embrace bohemian style.</p>
            </div>
          </div>
          <div class="second-text">
            <p>ECO</p>
            <p>POSITIVITY</p>
            <p>COLLECTION</p>
          </div>
          <div class="second2-text">
            <p>Make a difference,</p>
            <p>be the change.</p>
          </div>
          <div class="second">
            <a href="#"><img src="https://i.ibb.co/4tVLfzn/paisley.webp" alt="Paisley" style="max-width: 270px;"></a>
          </div>
          <div class="third">
            <a href="#"><img src="https://i.ibb.co/CVw2t2R/Spring-HUes.webp" alt="SpringHues" style="max-width: 310px;"></a>
          </div>
          <div class="third-text">
            <p>SPRING HUES</p>
          </div>
          <div class="third2-text">
            <p>Colours That Celebrate</p>
            <p>Spring.</p>
          </div>
          <div class="see-more">
            <a href="#" class="button">SEE MORE</a>
          </div>
          <div class="background-rect"></div>
        </td>
      </tr>
      <!-- SOCIAL MEDIA ICONS -->
      <div>
        <td class="container2">
          <div class="background2"></div>
          <a href="#" class="background-text" style="background-size: 100%;"></a>
          <div class="icons">
            <a href=""><img src="https://i.ibb.co/bQgqb1L/icons.png" alt=""></a>
          </div>
        </td>
      </div>
      <!-- BROWN BORDER -->
    </table>
  </center>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Don't use complex design for HTML email. See [Can I email](https://www.caniemail.com/search/?s=position). Many email clients does not support many CSS rules. So, the best choice is design use **image**; the good choice is use super very simple design.

Comment: Similar questions [1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55832155/email-template-not-being-rendered-properly-by-gmail-and-outlook), [2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51381938/html-email-template-not-working-outlook), [3](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61633896/css-email-template-at-outlook-does-not-display-correctly).